# Fatal error: 'config.h' file not found in react-native@0.68

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run a simple react native app on iOS. Recently React Native community have showed up some big updates, I guess that problem raised because of this new version. Because I just init new project and tried to run on iOS, it just throws error, On android its working fine but iOS isn't working. I have tried every solution but the question that peoples posted are lower version then 0.68 I guess, And there is a lot changes in react-native@0.68. Here is my react native info:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.4
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7267U CPU @ 3.10GHz
    Memory: 39.15 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.18 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.10.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.06.13.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.5, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.2 AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546
    Xcode: 13.4.1/13F100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.15 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.68.2 => 0.68.2 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

AND HERE IS THE OUTPUT AFTER RUNNING `npx react-native run-is`

```
yarn run v1.22.18
$ react-native run-ios
info Found Xcode workspace "carchaze.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace carchaze.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme carchaze -destination id=281B8E0D-0F76-4F58-9290-06986344B5AA")
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening carchaze.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace carchaze.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme carchaze -destination id=281B8E0D-0F76-4F58-9290-06986344B5AA

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

note: Using new build system
note: Planning
Analyze workspace

Create build description
Build description signature: 24ae75df6fda02487e58c5e870d14769
Build description path: /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/24ae75df6fda02487e58c5e870d14769-desc.xcbuild

note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
CompileC /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/libevent-dummy.o /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/libevent/libevent-dummy.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'libevent' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target x86_64-apple-ios11.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu11 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG\=1 -DDEBUG\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -fobjc-abi-version\=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -index-store-path /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/libevent-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/libevent-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/libevent-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/libevent-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent/include -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/libevent -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/libevent -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/libevent/include -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent -include /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/libevent/libevent-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/libevent-dummy.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/libevent-dummy.dia -c /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/libevent/libevent-dummy.m -o /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/libevent-dummy.o -index-unit-output-path /Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/libevent-dummy.o

CompileC /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vlog_is_on.o /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/vlog_is_on.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'glog' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -target x86_64-apple-ios11.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu++14 -stdlib\=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG\=1 -DDEBUG\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -index-store-path /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Index/DataStore -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog/include -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/glog -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -include /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/glog/glog-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vlog_is_on.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vlog_is_on.dia -c /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/vlog_is_on.cc -o /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vlog_is_on.o -index-unit-output-path /Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vlog_is_on.o
In file included from /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/vlog_is_on.cc:35:
In file included from /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/utilities.h:73:
/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/base/mutex.h:105:10: fatal error: 'config.h' file not found
#include "config.h"           // to figure out pthreads support
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

CompileC /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/utilities.o /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/utilities.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'glog' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -target x86_64-apple-ios11.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu++14 -stdlib\=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG\=1 -DDEBUG\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -index-store-path /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Index/DataStore -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog/include -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/glog -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -include /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/glog/glog-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/utilities.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/utilities.dia -c /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/utilities.cc -o /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/utilities.o -index-unit-output-path /Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/utilities.o
In file included from /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/utilities.cc:32:
In file included from /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/utilities.h:73:
/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/base/mutex.h:105:10: fatal error: 'config.h' file not found
#include "config.h"           // to figure out pthreads support
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

CompileC /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/symbolize.o /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/symbolize.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'glog' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -target x86_64-apple-ios11.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu++14 -stdlib\=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG\=1 -DDEBUG\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -index-store-path /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Index/DataStore -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog/include -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/glog -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -I/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -include /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/glog/glog-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/symbolize.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/symbolize.dia -c /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/symbolize.cc -o /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/symbolize.o -index-unit-output-path /Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/symbolize.o
In file included from /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/symbolize.cc:55:
In file included from /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/utilities.h:73:
/Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/base/mutex.h:105:10: fatal error: 'config.h' file not found
#include "config.h"           // to figure out pthreads support
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.


2022-06-19 22:38:25.298 xcodebuild[40727:215217] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-06-19 22:38:25.298 xcodebuild[40727:215217] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vlog_is_on.o /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/vlog_is_on.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'glog' from project 'Pods')
    CompileC /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/utilities.o /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/utilities.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'glog' from project 'Pods')
    CompileC /Users/atifkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/carchaze-falkqfsrsbarnffmcealtkufybsn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/symbolize.o /Users/atifkhan/Downloads/project/React_Native_Projects/Carchaze/carchaze/ios/Pods/glog/src/symbolize.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'glog' from project 'Pods')
(3 failures)

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

It's frustrating, I work on it over 7 hours. I have read a lot of docs, but still didn't find any solution. It would be pleasure if someone have the solution of it.

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of research, but suddenly i saw a pkg called react-native-clean-project. I just run this command in my project directory `npx react-native-clean-project` and then just `yarn run ios` my project run successfully. I have no idea what this pkg did, but for sure it didn't downgrade my pkg, react-native is still on latest version and project is now running on IOS & Android both. This pkg is a lot helpful